# Using Intrinsic Content Size + Compression/Hugging priorities in StackView

Tags: autolayout, uistackview

I am trying to have a table view cell be laid out with automatic dimensions using `estimatedRowHeight` and automatic dimensions.  The cell will hold a Stack View in its content view.

TheStack View is vertical axis and holds three arranged sub view.  A label followed by a view, with three labels as subviews, following by a label. Its alignment is center.  Its

My goal is for the intrinsic content size (height specifically) determine the height of the Stack View.

The ultimately goal is to have these three vertical arranged subviews determine the height of the Stack View, which determines the height of the content view and therefore the tableview cell which will dynamically receive this height.

The middle arranged subview is a "container" view that holds three labels.  Each label has a constant height of 22.  The reason I want this container layer in between the labels and the stack view is because it just simpler to do these specific constraints outside of the Stack View's control.  However, I want this container view's intrinsic content size (something like 22 + 22 + 22 + spacing/margin) to factor into the Stack View's intrinsic content size.

Now I know UIView's by default don't have an intrinsic content size.  Does that mean I  have to give this container view a custom class and override `intrinsicContentSize` to inform the StackView of the three labels height inside of it?

Comment: Its getting complex to imagine you ui in mind. Can you post some screenshots

Comment: sorry i've since used a different strategy here.  one point of interest is that it seems UIVIew does have an intrinsic content size if it has subviews with intrinsic content size.